# How does Workbench.aspx in Office365 get local files?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I'm sure this is a really simple answer but I can't see the connection.

Essentially I'm playing with the SPFx tutorials and I just uploaded the workbench.aspx to my shared documents and the hello world webpart is reflecting the changes I make locally. But in the aspx file I don't see a reference to anything external so I'm a little confused as to how it's getting those local files. I assume it has something with gulp serve but yea I'm not seeing the connection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The workbench.aspx inherits from `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ClientSidePage` which I assume uses the specified `ClientSideApplicationId` to load a specific Client Side Application.

The id `8be81a5c-af38-4bb2-af97-afa3b64dfbed` is the `Workbench app` which as part of the html includes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_20160907.004/sp-module-loader_dd0eb85580e3cfe29779ada495761ff5.js">
</script>
```

This loader has the following starting points hardcoded:

- `https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js`
- `http://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js`

These files and the rest of your `application` is served by `gulp-connect` which you start with the command `gulp serve` (--nobrowser)

Comment: Thanks Per, great answer, makes perfect sense. It's hard to see what's happening in the Aspx file itself but having the loader call the scripts gulp is serving is pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running Gulp on Node and have to load "unsafe script" in your browser  you are accepting the script source as your local machine. The workbench in the dev tenant is unaware of the script source which is why you get a warning. The workbench doesn't access your local machine, it's Gulp that serves the workbench both locally and in Office 365.

And that's pretty amazing, making our programming life much easier...